# Type hints when returning dynamically mixed generic types in Python

Tags: python, generics, types

I am writing a function that takes a tuple with an undetermined number of objects of the same class, but with varying generic types. The return values of this function will be a same-sized tuple with items of the specified types.

How can I rewrite the `process` function below to make this work? This current attempt requires that all objects use the same type. So it would work if `a`, `b`, and `c` were all specified as `int`. But in my use-case, types should be mixable and tuple size should be dynamic.

```py
from typing import Generic, Tuple, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class Command(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, value: T):
        self.value = value

def process(commands: Tuple[Command[T], ...]) -> Tuple[T, ...]:
    return tuple([cmd.value for cmd in commands])

a = Command[int](1)
b = Command[str]("foobar")
c = Command[int](2)
a_, b_, c_ = process((a, b, c))

# How to make my language server understand that a_, b_, c_ are int, str, int?
```

Comment: Note that since python 3.10 you don't need to use `typing.Tuple` etc anymore, `tuple` itself supports type hinting: `tuple[T,...]`

Comment: The purpose is consistency. While the `Command` class can be used with any type, usage of a single instance of `Command` gives feedback on which type it supposed to use.

Comment: @IzaakCornelis Yes, realized that, hence the removed comment :)

Comment: I've run into this issue before. Python does not seem to support type-hinting in tuple unpacking..